# Error with Google Checkout and Lib Varien when upgrading Magento from 1.7.0.2 to 1.8.0

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, updates, magento-1.8

I am in the process of incrementally upgrading my site from 1.6.1 to 1.8.1 however going from 1.7.0.2 to 1.8.0 I am having errors that are not allowing me to continue updating.

After updating Mage_All_Latest I get the following errors:

```
CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Lib_Varien 1.8.1.0 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.7.0.2

CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.8.0.0 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.7.0.2
```

Lib_Google_Checkout is currently at 1.5.0 and Lib_Varien is currently at 1.8.0.0.

I've tried upgrading them individually by alas the same errors. Does anybody have an idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 1.8.X+ removes Google Checkout, because Google announced the product's end of life in November of 2013.

You can safely disable Google Checkout extension in Magento 1.8+.

Cheers!